# Event handling between two custom controls

Tags: event-handling, custom-controls, sapui5

I have two custom controls. Control A attaches an event handler on Control B by calling

```
b.attachEventName( function(event, data){ ... })
```

after instantiating b.

Control B reacts on a click and fires the relevant event by doing something like this:

```
this.fireEventName( { key: value } );
```

I observe that I don't have access to the object, I gave as parameter in the firing of the event in the attached function in control A. How can I get access to that object?

PS: For clarification: I want to reuse Control B, and different controls, which use B might want to attach different functions for a specific event.

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with syntax you are using to attach event to the control.

If you want to pass an object along with the event object when firing the event, code would be:

```
b.attachEventName(oData, function(oEvent){
    // your stuff
});
```

Comment: But I want to send data by firing the event. My solution now is to give the function from Control A to Control B which then attaches the function to the event with this.attachEventName( object, functionFromClassA), then directly firing the event.

Comment: you are still able send data when firing an event by `this.fireEventName( { key: value } );`

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
b.attachEventName(function(event, data) {
  var sKey = event.getParameter("key")
});
```

The second parameter `data` in this function is the data that you potentialy passed when registering the event listener as described above by Dopedev.

BR
Chris